# If I deny G-d access to my thoughts. Would He read it anyway? Are my thoughts publics by default?

Tags: theology, sin, thought

If I deny G-d access to my thoughts. Would He read it anyway?

For G-d, Are my thoughts publics by default?

Comment: I don't think it works that way. Hashem is beyond time so before you even existed He "knew" your thoughts.

Comment: G-d is all-powerful. We can't deny Him anything.

Comment: One of the [13 Principles of Faith from Maimonides](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/332555/jewish/Maimonides-13-Principles-of-Faith.htm) is that G-d knows all of our thoughts and actions.

Comment: How do you "deny" access?

Answer (score 2):

In [Vayikra 25:17](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.25.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) it says:

> You shall not therefore defraud one another; but thou shalt fear thy G-d: for I am the L-rd your G-d.

On this pasuk, [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Leviticus.25.17.1?ven=Pentateuch_with_Rashi%27s_commentary_by_M._Rosenbaum_and_A.M._Silbermann,_1929-1934&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) explains the proper way to answering someone who says “Who knows whether I had any intention to do him evil?”. Rashi says:

> Scripture therefore states: “but thou shalt fear thy G-d”! — **He Who knows men’s thoughts, He knows it!** **In all cases** where it is a matter of conscience (more lit., a matter handed over to the heart), when no one knows the truth except the one who has the thought in his heart, Scripture always states: “but be afraid of thy G-d”! (emphasis mine)

G-d is the One *"Who knows men’s thoughts"*.

Also, in [Tehillim 94:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.94.11?ven=Sefaria_Community_Translation&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), David HaMelech writes:

> G-d knows the thoughts of humankind; that they are nothing.

See also the commentary of the [Radak](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.94.11?ven=Sefaria_Community_Translation&lang=bi&with=Radak&lang2=en) on this pasuk in Tehillim.